# I can't find where can I get the POI results in using Google Maps SDK for iOS and Google Places for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, point-of-interest

My app using Google maps the SDK, but not from Google found on the official document about the POI retrieval method, I demand is this: to a certain point as the center, in a certain value of circle diameter to retrieve certain places, such as retrieval from places such as hospitals, schools, bus, subway, I want to find a way to can return to these results, but don't know where the document。Who knows? Please help me.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Places search is currently available only via web services:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

There is also a feature request in the issue tracker to add places text search in iOS SDK:

https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/35829470

Feel free to star this feature request and subscribe to further notifications from Google.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The first url address helps me.I send net request to google webservice,then get the data from the response . Finally add the info to the mapview.Your answer helps me ,thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.